Custom Gateway filter order in Spring Cloud Gateway
I am exploring Spring Cloud Gateway. I want to introduce a custom HTTPHeadersFilter for all the routes.
Also i want to protect the gateway with authentication .Hence am using Spring Security. I have defined the SecurityFilterChain with appropriate objects.
In my HTTPHeaders filter i want to extract the Token set in SpringSecurityContext which gets set during the executing of SpringSecurity filters. But in my code i am getting access denied from SpringSecurityContext which can come if the token is not set.
I would like to understand if the order of execution of CloudGateway Filters . Can the gateway filters get executed before security filters. I don't think that should happen and probably some issue in my SpringSecurityContext initialization.

no, security filters are the first thing the request will go through, but this is way too abstract, please show your code so that we can analyze a specific usecase
